# Find sides of isosceles triangle inside a circle with line segment lengths as 5 and 4 as shown in the link. pls help!

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Pls see the diagram below. I tried to use similar triangles and came to my wits end. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: similar triangles is the way. you just have to draw the line EC.

Comment: E is tangent point?

Comment: I did that but how does EC help? EC is not parallel to AB....

Comment: Thats all that is given of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and define: $a=CD$, $b=CH$, $h=AH$. By power of point $D$ with respect to the circle you have:
$$
a(a+2b)=4\cdot 9,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
a^2+2ab=36.
$$
By Pythagoras' theorem you have:
$$
(a+b)^2+h^2=9^2,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
a^2+2ab+b^2+h^2=81.
$$
By substituting here $a^2+2ab$ from the previous equation one gets:
$$
b^2+h^2=81-36,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
x^2=45.
$$

Comment: Omg thank you! I wasn't familiar with power of a point with respect to a circle. I searched it up and learned something new!! Thank you again!!